# Merging Multiple records into a Unique records with all the non-null values

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Suppose I have 3 records :

```
P1||1234|
P1|56001||
P1|||NJ
```

I want to merge these 3 records into one with all the attributes. Final record :

```
P1|56001|1234|NJ
```

Is there any way to achieve this in Unix/Linux?

Comment: Neither Linux nor Unix is a programming language, they're operating systems.  Consider tagging this with your desired programming language to get answers from their respective community.

Comment: @TylerD as I understood the op, he doesn't want a specific language, but just a solution that works in a shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, 1st row you have `1234`, 2nd row you have `56001`.

I don't get why in your final result, the `56001` goes before `1234`. I assume it is a typo/mistake.

an awk-oneliner could do the job:

```
awk -F'|' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)if($i)a[$1]=(a[$1]?a[$1]"|":"")$i}END{print $1"|"a[$1]}'
```

with your data:

```
kent$  echo "P1||1234|
P1|56001||
P1||NJ"|awk -F'|' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)if($i)a[$1]=(a[$1]?a[$1]"|":"")$i}END{print $1"|"a[$1]}'
P1|1234|56001|NJ
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you ask solution with bash, awk, sed etc.
You could try something like

```
$ cat test.txt 
P1||1234|
P1|56001||
P1|||NJ
$ cat test.txt | awk -F'|' '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) print $i }' | egrep '.+' | sort | uniq | awk 'BEGIN{ c = "" } { printf c $0; c = "|" } END{ printf "\n" }'
1234|56001|NJ|P1
```

Briefly, `awk` splits the lines with '|' separator and prints each field to a line. `egrep` removes the empty lines. After that, `sort` and `uniq` removes multiple attributes. Finally, `awk` merges the lines with '|' separator.

Update:

If I understand correctly, here's what you seek for;

```
$ cat test.txt | awk -F'|' '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) if($i) col[i]=$i } END{ for (i = 1; i <= length(col); i++) printf col[i] (i == length(col) ? "\n" : "|")}'
P1|56001|1234|NJ
```

Comment: apart from the `cat|awk|grep|sort|uniq|awk`, `P1` should be at the beginning of the line, right?

Comment: @Kent, I am not sure. As you see, I haven't considered that in my solution. If so, your solution should be taken.

Comment: Alper, @Kent thanks for your answers. I think, I failed to make the requirement clear. I am looking for a solution, that will take the non-null values from multiple records among the same column and will prepare the final record.<br/> i.e Since the 1st record has 3rd col as not-null '1234', the 2nd record has 2nd col. as not null '56001' and the 3rd record has 4th col not-null with value 'NJ'. the Final record expected<br/>    P1|56001|1234|NJ